# Как можно получить данные для RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, retrofit, null

Начал пробовать работать с Retofit'ом, и сразу столько проблем..)
У меня есть RecyclerView с двумя ViewHolder'ами, где пытаюсь получить данные с моих моделей(начал с одной) - в логи приходит *type*:

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
            DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
            Log.d("type",jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss().get(1).getmControls().get(2).getTitle()+"");
            adapter = new DataAdapter(response.body());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Теперь задался вопросом как корректно отобразить его в моём recyclerView(при условии что буду передавать несколько значение типа: *type*). Так как помимо моего значения *type* приходит сообщение:

> 09-13 09:20:40.958 2798-2798/com.company.secondproject E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: у тебя jsonResponse это TextNumeric, а response.body() - это List<TextNumeric>. Посмотри что хранится в response.body() во время получения ответа

Comment: Извините, а как я могу именно это посмотреть?

Comment: Ну ты же скинул скрин режима откладки, в этом же окне в поле Variables (переменные) раскрой переменную response и посмотри что в body.

Comment: response ->
body = null

Comment: ну вот и ответ. в запросе ничего не приходит, либо приходит, но не то, что тебе нужно.

Comment: запрос правильно выполняешь?

Comment: Скорей всего просто ничего не приходит.
Не уверен, стараюсь делать по гайдам.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45141/discussion-between-vadim-morozov-and-nikotin-n).

Comment: @Nikotin N добавил параметры в интерфейс, вызов адаптера также переписал, не помогло(

Comment: в обсуждение зайди